# Rmarkdown directing output file into a directory

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I found a really nice trick ([link](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Rmarkdown-custom-knit-hook-to-compile-a-multi-part-document)) to a function of knitr, where you can save your output html into an output folder and under a different filename.

The only thing you have to head to the header is the following:

```
title: "analysis"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y, %H:%M')`"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding, 
                        output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir, 'analysis.html')) })
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
```

This works on my Mac 'sometimes' very well, but sometimes it has problems to find the out_dir variable...

I first thought about executing the chunks first, so the variable is set... But this didn't solved the problem...

I also restarted R session and this didn't helped.

The last step was closing R, saving the workspace and after reopening R and loading workspace it works like a charm again.

I could not find the original post, where somebody recommended this trick...

**EXACT WORKFLOW TO REPRODUCE**

open new project, name it test in a new folder
create a r markdown document
change the header to:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y, %H:%M')`"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding, 
                        output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir, 'analysis.html')) })
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
---

```{r write quant output files}
out_dir <- 'test'
if(!file.exists(out_dir)) {
  dir.create(out_dir)
}
```
````

save the document as test.Rmd
click the knit button (html is now removed from the options of the button)
This will fail!

Close the project!
Click on save environment!

Open the Project and click knit!
Everything works.

execute rm(list=ls()) everything works afterwards again

Comment: Imagine running that code in a clean R session. How does R know what `out_dir` is if you haven't defined it? When this works after reloading the workspace, it's because `out_dir` is an object carried forward from your last R session, which allows the code to work even though it shouldn't.

Comment: You are right, but the command get evaluated at the of the rmakrdown process when the html gets created. I also can set the variable out_dir by hand and there is still the same problem and Rstudio complains that out_dir does not exist... If the script runs once, I can also execute rm(list=ls()) and it works afterwards as well... So I think it isn't just an issue of setting the variable...

Comment: There's no way this code can work without you specifying that variable. Why it seems to work is hard to say without a complete description of the workflow you're following.

Comment: I added the correct workflow. It is really strange, since everything works, if I at least reopen the project...
Not sure if anyone else can reproduce this... But it also makes no concrete sense to me. I just thought, that the command will be evaluated in the end of the whole markdown process...

Comment: Just found the link to the original trick

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try setting the `out_dir` variable in the function you are giving `knit` to render:

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      out_dir <- 'test';
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding, 
                        output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir, 'analysis.html')) })
```

Comment: I mean, my whole function/rmarkdown is working fine, after reopening the r project... Even if I remove the whole environment which is already set... So I am wondering, why this happens. Or can anybody not reproduce the scenario I posted? I tried it on a Mac and two Windows computers and it is reproducible in all of them and works after reopening the R project.

Comment: Yes,  I can't get it to work on my machine if I don't set the `out_dir` variable

Comment: I neither can't reproduce it without setting the out_dir variable as described by @NicE

Comment: I would also include the `if(!file.exists(out_dir)) {
  dir.create(out_dir)
}`part directly into the knitting-function. In this way it works for me and also it kind of makes sense: you have all the knitting-things in the header and can use the body for your content - how it should be

Comment: I am also wondering why it works, given that the [page originally describing the trick](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Rmarkdown-custom-knit-hook-to-compile-a-multi-part-document) says _"The knit: field (a currently undocumented hook) replaces rmarkdown::render with a custom function specifying parameters for the rendering. Yes, unfortunately it has to be a huge one-liner unless you have your own R package."_ Anyway, it works for me...

Comment: I kind of like NicE version and I also added the if exists part Julian suggested to my function and it seems to work fine... I only wonder, why is the `out_dir` variable, which is set in the render function, also available in my code junks? I was wondering, if I set it in the function, do I have to set it twice... But after a few test, the variable really seems to be available. So I have to set it really only once... Can anyone explain this? I thought the variable should be invisible from the outside.

Comment: This function must be a oneliner. see [comment](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/277#issuecomment-76539492) on github. This still works in rstudio v1.1.383 , knitr v1.17

Comment: The out_dir is super customizable. You can even write to another directory elsewhere e.g. `out_dir = '../reports';`

Answer (score 4):

I found it cumbersome to write the output-file name so I swapped the `output_file` to `output_dir` argument but kept the rest of the code. In this way my Rmarkdown is still knitted into a subdirectory but with the `inputFile` name. Also, if the directory does not exist, it is created

```
---
title: "title"
author: "gordon freeman"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"

knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
      out_dir <- "reports";
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding,
                        output_dir=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir))})
---
```

Comment: This was almost perfect, except that if you use caching in your r chunks in the Rmarkdown file, the cache directory is still generated at project level  :-(