# function to get filename without full path in YAML header of RMarkdown document

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to modify the behavior of RStudio's knit button, by changing the directory to which it writes the output of knitting the Rmd file. I have started with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937800/743568), but instead of having the filename given by a fixed string, I'd like to have the output filename based on the Rmd filename. However, the variable `inputFile` includes the full path to the Rmd file. Is there a way to get only the filename without the path?

The header I am working with that produces the full path+filename where I'd like just the filename (`test2` is a directory that I created in the current working directory):

```
---
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {rmarkdown::render(inputFile,encoding=encoding, output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), "test2", paste0(substr(inputFile,1,nchar(inputFile-4),".html"))) })
output: html_document
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still interested in a command that would directly give me the input filename, as specified in the question, but I found a workaround for the particular issue, using regex in the `substr` call, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214677/r-find-the-last-dot-in-a-string):

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {rmarkdown::render(inputFile,encoding=encoding, output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), "test2", paste0(substr(inputFile,rev(gregexpr("/", inputFile)[[1]])[1]+1,nchar(inputFile)-4),".html"))) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, knitr comes with a function `current_input()` that gives you the name of the Rmd-file as a string. And `tools::file_path_sans_ext()` will remove the extension.

But to solve the exact problem of the OP, there are probably better options today, for example, [knitr options](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.15), the package [ezknitr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ezknitr), RStudio "Knit Directory" [button](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-rmarkdown-chunks/2267), or [`here::here()`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=here).